# ¿Cómo debería hacer un count donde se condicionen las fechas?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, ms-access-2013

En el colegio nos mandaron a hacer en *Access* una base de datos de ventas, tiene id de producto, producto, fecha de ingreso, fecha de venta y precio, el deber consistía en mostrar cuantos productos ingresaron a bodega en noviembre, con este código siempre me sale 0 a pesar de haber 12 productos de noviembre, ¿está mal el `WHERE`?

```
SELECT Count(*) AS bodega_noviembre
FROM ventas
WHERE fecha_ingreso BETWEEN "01/11/2020" AND "30/11/2020"
```

Comment: Si la respuesta de abajo te soluciono el problema te recuerdo marcarla como la que funciono con el tilde verde. Saludos.

Answer (score 5):

Si estas usando Access las fechas van de la siguiente manera `#2/2/2012#`

De esta manera la consulta deberia funcionarte como lo menciono aqui abajo:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS bodega_noviembre FROM ventas WHERE fecha_ingreso BETWEEN #01/11/2020# AND #30/11/2020#
```